# problem with using apollo client mutate outside render

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, use-effect

I want to have a custom component named AuthRoute not only to check if certain data is available in redux but also verify token with graphql

here is what I've done :

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authUser, ...rest }) => {
  const you_must_go_back_to_login = <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      (<Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/user/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}
      />)
    }
  />

  const continue_journey = <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      (<Component {...props} />)
    }
  />

  const [dest, setDest] = useState(you_must_go_back_to_login)
  const [checkThat, setCheckThat] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    client.mutate({
      mutation: VERIFY_TOKEN_MUTATION,
      variables: { token }
    }).then(result => {
      // setDest(continue_journey)
      setCheckThat(true)
    })
    return () => {
      console.log()
    };
  }, [])

  // if(authUser) {
  if (checkThat) {

    return continue_journey

  } else {
    return you_must_go_back_to_login;
  }
}
```

here is the steps I need them to be done:

1. run mutate
2. setDest to one of you_must_go_to_login or continue_journey
3. setCheckThat or something like that to true or false based on token verified or not
4. return dest as a result

now I've got this error :

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

### UPDATE

I changed my code to this but I still get the same error

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authUser, ...rest }) => {
  const you_must_go_back_to_login = (<Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      (<Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/user/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}
      />)
    }
  />)

  const continue_journey = (<Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      (<Component {...props} />)
    }
  />)

  // const [dest, setDest] = useState(you_must_go_back_to_login)
  const [checkThat, setCheckThat] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true

    if (isSubscribed) {
      getToken();
    }

    return () => isSubscribed = false
  }, []);

  const getToken = async (sig) => {
    const data = await mutate(VERIFY_TOKEN_MUTATION, { token })
    console.log(data)
    setCheckThat(true);
    console.log(checkThat)
    return;
  };

  return checkThat ? continue_journey : you_must_go_back_to_login;
}
```

Comment: error is caused by rendering redirect earlier than getting data ... instead `useEffect` you can use simple `useQuery` (mutation is for changing remote data, using query you can pass variable and return answer, too) and use `!data` for rendering loading befor decision to redirect or give access

Comment: @xadm, Thank you for mentioning that, I'm using django graphql jwt and the problem is that verifytoken for that is a mutation :/ that caused me theeeese headaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is caused by rendering redirect earlier than getting data.

**Normlly** ... instead `useEffect` you can use simple `useQuery` and use condition `loading` or `!data` for rendering some `<Loading/>` befor decision to redirect or give access (rendering redirect or guarded content).

Mutation is generally used for changing remote data. By using query you can pass variable and return answer, too.

> I'm using django graphql jwt and the problem is that verifytoken for that is a mutation

In general/usually token is passed by header for requests and API returns response or errors (for missing/expired token). Usually you have an option to query current user for being logged verification.

... **in this case we want to use mutation**

... instead `client.mutate` we can use hooks - [useMutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/mutations) or better [API example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#example-2) ( apollo docs :] ) - to get access to `loading state` before making decision

```
const [verifyToken, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation( VERIFY_TOKEN_MUTATION, variables: { token } );
```

Problems?
 - **mutations are not called at start** - `loading` won't be true on the beggining;
 - returned data.

For firing mutation at start we can use `useEffect`, for returned data we can use `onCompleted` handler but we can simply use `data` - should be undefined/nulled at start, usable for conditions.

Something like this should work (we don't need await etc. - `data`, `loading`, `error` will be updated automatically):

```
useEffect(() => {
  verifyToken(); // ariables passed earlier, can be passed here
}, []);

if( !data ) return <Loading />

return data.someSuccessVerifiedField ? continue_journey : you_must_go_back_to_login;
```

Comment: I did exactly as you say, but the thing is that I have to refresh the page again, I think something here causes data not to be updated without refresh

Comment: try to use `onComplete` with `setCheckThat` ... using `data` after `await verifyToken()` should be possible, too (check with console.log) ... and `console.log(data)` in this render (check it changes) ... maybe rendering `<Route/>` is unnecessary(on success), render `<Component/>`

Answer (score 0):

The warning is pretty self-explanatory -

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Specially this part -

> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

You are using `useEffect` in a wrong way. You should not put your mutation inside `useEffect`. What you can do is - take the mutation outside of the `useEffect`.

```
const [dest, setDest] = useState(you_must_go_back_to_login)
const [checkThat, setCheckThat] = useState(false)

  client.mutate({
      mutation: VERIFY_TOKEN_MUTATION,
      variables: { token }
    }).then(result => {
      // setDest(continue_journey)
      setCheckThat(true)
    })
    return () => {
      console.log()
    };


  useEffect(() => {
    // if(authUser) {
    if (checkThat) {

      return <continue_journey/>

    } else {
      return <you_must_go_back_to_login/>;
    }
  }, [checkThat])
}
```

So now mutation will run, then set `checkThat` variable. And then `useEffect` will be triggered which will return based on the value of `checkThat`

Comment: Thank you , I tested it and got this error :
```Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.```

Comment: just return  wrapping like this - `<continue_journey/>` and `<you_must_go_back_to_login/>`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: the error was because of the ``` return () => { console.log ...``` line , I removed that and added those </> to that lines but finally I've got the same clean up error as before (the error I've got at first)